# Invert a 2D --> 2D non-linear function

Tags: python

I'm sorry if this is an unusual way to write a question here, since the scope of it seems quite large (to me). I'd be happy to be directed to pre-defined packages that already do what I'm needing, indeed I hope there is (should be?) a standardised solution to my question.  I was wondering if there is any help out there? I'm still learning Python through a project I'm doing, and I feel I'm slightly weak on certain points...

Ok so here goes: I would like to invert a 2D --> 2D function in python, but none of my efforts have succeeded yet.

Let's say I have two relationships in a (non-linear) systems of equations, so

a = f(x,y)

b = g(x,y)

where both f and g are continuous and invertible, and x and y have a certain pre-defined rectangular domain. a and b also have their own rectangular domain, but it is different from that of x and y.

**Some extra info on f and g:** One of the functions will be linear, let's call this f. So, a = f(x,y) = q*x + p*y + r (where q, p and r are known constants). In Python terms, I guess you would write a[ i, j ] = q*x[ i ] + p*y[ j ]. The other function, g, has no analytic expression but looks similar to k*sin(x) + l*sin(y), for x and y between 0 and pi/2.

Moreover, the overall "mother-function" that I wish to make a 3D surface plot of, takes a and b as arguments. Calling the mother function M, we then have that M = M(a,b) = M(f(x,y),g(x,y)). So far so good.

The essence of the problem is that I need to first choose a pair (a,b) on the "mother-grid", then find the corresponding pair (x,y) that gives rise to this particular (a,b). f and g do not have any analytically "simple" inverses however, and I need to find these numerically.

So the basic question is, *"given a[ i ] and b[ j ] as two sorted lists, and given x[ ii ] and y [ jj ] that are used to obtain each a and b, how do I find the two inverse functions x = inv1 (a,b) and y = inv2 (a,b)?"*

PS. I have tried the "cheap way" of circumventing this problem by first choosing a (x,y) pair, calculating a tentative (A,B) pair and then interpolate this into the pre-defined (a,b) mesh as best as I could. However, since the (x,y) mesh and the (a,b) meshes are (quite) different, the corresponding "fitting error" always make the end result come out jagged and messy (I have a control scenario where I know what the end result should look like, before doing my own cases). This is because I am essentially forcing the values of A and B onto the height of the M function at position (a,b) if that makes sense. I've tried averaging and smoothing "cheats" to this, but it is still not passable imo. Hence, I really need to choose an (a,b) pair FIRST, and then only finding the relevant (x,y) pair after that.

Note: Some parameters in the M-function depends directly on x and y, hence the need for knowing the exact values of x and y.

Comment: Can you describe how functions `f, g` are defined in a bit more detail? Can you give a formalized generic form with parameters? How do you know they are continuous and invertible, for example?

Comment: I added some extra info on the functions. Forgot to add that my project is in physics, where - you know - all functions are always continuous. :-)

Comment: You don't need to specify "edit:" to make your question look like a revision history. Those are available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63196567/revisions) if anybody is interested.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know that. I'm new to this site and I was once instructed to change my original post instead of commenting (like I'm doing now). Good to know there is a history-function like the one you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the additional information!  I think you can solve this directly and then analytically.

Starting with your final result `(a, b)`:

First solve against `a` to find your x-y line, e.g.:

```
a = qx + py + r
y = (qx + r - a) / -p
```

Since you said it is monotonically increasing, I just solve for `y` for simplicity.

Next, plug this into your non-analytic `g` using a simple binary search across `x`:

```
def invert(a, b):
    def get_y(x):
        return (Q * x + R - a) / -P
    
    def g_constrained(x):
        return g(x, func(x))

    x = binary_search(g_constrained, b, min_x, max_x, guess_x)
    y = get_y(x)
    return x, y
```

Note that your function is not guaranteed to have a single solution in general, consider a planar solution for `g` that looks like an arc, since `f` is a line, you can have two intersections.  You will need to decide what you want to do with this information.

---

**Previous concerns**

I am suspicious of your claim that `a = f(x,y)` is continuous and invertible.

Put succinctly: **if your function `z = f(x, y)` doesn't intersect the plane `z = K` in exactly one point for every `K`, it is not invertible**.

For a detailed example:

Consider some point, and 4 points around it - here I use `(0,0)` and unit length, for convenience.

```
z = f(0,0)

a = f(-1,0)
b = f(1,0)

p = f(0,-1)
q = f(0,1)
```

If `f` provides a scalar value (or anything where `x < y` and `y < z` implies `x < z`), then we have a problem.

Since `f` is continuous and invertible, either `a < z < b` or `b < z < a`, and likewise for `p` and `q`.  So `f-inv(z+)` will map to two different values, one on the line `(-1, 0) -> (1, 0)` and one on the line `(0, -1) -> (0, 1)`.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "either a < z < b or b > z > a" ? To me, these seem like the same thing. Anyway, there is only one unique pair of (x,y) to every unique pair of (a,b), and f and g are monotonically increasing on both of their arguments. Is that a sufficient requirement do you think?

Comment: Thanks for the typo catch in the inequalities.  If `f` and `g` are monotonically increasing in both arguments, then `f(0,0) < f(0, 1)` and `f(0, 0) < f(1, 0)`.  Suppose `f(0, 1) = 10` and `f(1, 0) = 20`. There must be a value of `f-inv(10)` of the form `f(x, 0)` for `x in (0, 1)` as well, so `f` is not invertible, it has 2 options (in practice there are will be a continuous line of infinite options for `f-inv(Z)`).

Comment: Aha yes, thanks for pointing that out. My issue is different however, since I'm looking to invert two functions simultaneously. There will only be one pair of x and y that correspond to '(10,20)'. So while you are correct in the 2D --> 1D case, it is different in the 2D --> 2D case. So, only one unique pair of (x,y) = func-inv (10,20). It is similar to how (using my original notation) there can be several (x,y) pairs that give me the same a. So that 'a = f(x1,y1) = f(x2,y2)' etc, But only one of these pairs will give me my 'b = g(x1,y1) != g(x2,y2)'. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I had been thinking about that exact situation during lunch actually, and was coming back to comment that ;).  The intersection of the two solution lines can meet in a point (not necessarily always), so you can invert the final function `M(a, b) -> (c, d), (e, f)` in those cases

Comment: Hi there! Sorry for my absence, as I have been away over the weekend. I will start coding again tomorrow and will get back to you! All the best :-)